# How can I fix/improve the typings of my Decorator containing a Proxy?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-typings, proxy-pattern

I've written this decorator which uses a Proxy to read value from the local storage for a list of specified properties.

```
function StoredValues<T>(storageKey: string, storedProperties: Array<keyof T>) {
  function keyForProperty(property: string | symbol) {
    return `${storageKey}.${property.toString()}`;
  }

  function shouldUseStorage(property: string | symbol): boolean {
    return storedProperties.includes(property as keyof T); // Is it possible without type assertion ?
  }

  function actualDecorator(target: Function) { 
    // better return type ?
    const f: any = function (...args: any[]) { 
      return new Proxy(Reflect.construct(target, args), {
        get(target, property) {
          if (shouldUseStorage(property)) {
            const fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(keyForProperty(property));
            if (fromStorage) {
              console.log('From storage', fromStorage);
              // Warning !!! this will return a string (was number before)
              return fromStorage;
            }
          }
          console.log('Pass through', property);
          return target[property];
        },
        set(target: any, property: string | symbol, value: any): boolean {
          target[property] = value;
          if (shouldUseStorage(property)) {
            localStorage.setItem(keyForProperty(property), value);
          }
          console.log('Set', property, 'to', value);
          return true;
        },
      });
    };
    return f;
  }
  return actualDecorator;
}
```

I'm not quite satisfied with the typing I've used, particularly the `any` as return type. I've tried multiple things but I can't get quite the right typing.

For example if I use `new Proxy<T>()`, the compiler returns `Decorator function return type '(...args: any[]) => Bar' is not assignable to type 'void | typeof Bar'`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wg3gLABQCZCAZrggLwIDMADANwkC+JJAAgMoTZQApgBMAasGQBXQWAA8AIWBQAfAAoA5AFsAngGFcyANKDt6gDQIA2uqrZ1AXQCUJFGgyKoCQQA8IggHbCGDh4RKTk2ABuglBQAJbCgpTUdAAsLCTkCCDAAF60CABMGcQcxCSRStlVdP6CAO4IHqrOxLDY-mDYyIIAdMjYAOaqOVC9to6sbR1dPf1DI0rjuJMko8t4aQBsU+2d3X0Dw+sTuzMH88dLObmr5cQUkv7wcR0IfAIi4lIysgAqakgAmAg0Exm0AC4EJB4v5BhYgUJhAAFKDYAAOMQgcRkUIAgrFgNpZABrEzYCgIAGOAiZShPF5vMnaHBQVEYrHaVTotGYqAQSHQ6BxOEIAA+0O0mhA3RpYSyQggkig-gQAAMACT4REgsEmNi9LU8jn87S9fh8WHDRxsNVTMhlOmPZ7Yt5gAAW2EkyGEAFUwIIPjBQdzeZyoTCRYNxZLpbKoTKDsBVfLyIrlarESJ2XzsTJeiKUJJEmBQyaBQg0AhmRSqZMEAB6BsIACSGDiiHR2HQcRAPQQ9Q7nskiAFmMr6Cxr1VAH46Y7ws7Gaq4EqJAARQTtGD8KCqCBKUEQKGYBmu-xyulkJvZQQQPyedMqhBjpJz8JkPaQShQ5PaApLueCCqL0oGHmAv7+NolhOLSH5pneGYIHUjTst4XIAEqCBQPTwL0X7QJI8D7oed4WOBjgWKmWRkEeJFQEeFjGrm2iXvBNEIHElKqB6Xo+v6ga7rqZYsY4bEcRxBGUGimhBrqBQDLAEhyaCvRHi2fiaKozKsjmnIiZyYn2hJWRccBFAySpgjiSZNFfhcRwaJgMlCsCoLmNJ2CyUJoJ3LZNFPqqFleVZxn+WU4VXhJ9lzI56jIm4L7umikiDO6HnMYZYUSYFL6kRAliZaa9jZVkbBmFFWQBhA9FHpB2hMWGpoRsKooSmAUoysgFiVD89WOAmBiCMmcH+QeDF3oVTUCvYBS9dIpU0WZPHDvxAZWQZppiaN-kIIpyk+X01UaYIWk6QIemmptAqUQg83WYtZWVXZ5yxQs6g8HeGXTQ1CDqPwHn3X5tm5YRgiPQg5XPWwwMOtluUUMZEUILlq6SBuW7AruUxlEAA)

Comment: You are proxying at the wrong time. You should be returning a new class, and returning the proxy from the class's constructor. Class decorators *change the class itself*. They aren't called for every instance created.

Comment: @kelly how would you write it ?

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/NaknBW